# How to Pass Data from One frame to Another and to all other frames in the project?

Tags: java

I wanna want to pass or share data(values) from login frame to all frames in my project, H have made class of this variables like this

```
public class SharedData {

    public  String LoginName;

    public SharedData() {
    }

    /**
     * @return the LoginName
     */
    public String getLoginName() {
        return LoginName;
    }

    /**
     * @param LoginName the LoginName to set
     */
    public void setLoginName(String LoginName) {
        this.LoginName = LoginName;
    }
}
```

and from the first frame (login frame) I make object of this class and sets its username like this

```
 public  SharedData  data1=new SharedData();
    data1.setLoginName(Username_Login.getText().toString());
```

and from the second frame i get the value :

```
public  SharedData  data=new SharedData();
ogin_labelName.setText(data1.getLoginName().toString());
```

But finally it doesn’t work ... what is the problem or any solution ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Another option would be to use a `Singleton`. That way you'll only have one instance from the class and there's no need to create an object either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a bean class like :

```
public class SharedData {
        public  static String LoginName;

        public static void setLoginName(String LoginName) {
            SharedData.LoginName = LoginName;
        }

        public static String getLoginName() {
            return LoginName;
        }
    }
```

And use this class for setting and getting a values from another form  just calling this class for setting a value:

```
SharedData.setLoginName(Username_Login.getText().toString());
```

and for getting a value :

```
ogin_labelName.setText(SharedData.getLoginName(Username_Login.getText().toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new object in the second frame. So obviously, this second object doesn't contain the same data as the first one.

If you put a message in a box, and open another box, you won't find the message in it. Same with Java objects.

When the login frame constructs the main frame, it should pass the SharedData object it has created to the main frame constructor (or to a setter method):

```
SharedData data1 = new SharedData();
data1.setLoginName(Username_Login.getText().toString());

MainFrame frame = new MainFrame(data1);
```

You should also learn Java naming conventions and stick to them. Fields should start with a lower-case letter, and shouldn't contain underscores: `userNameLogin` instead of `Username_Login`. And there is no point in calling `toString()` on a String.